# mysql event which drops and then creates table based on query results

Tags: mysql, events

I am trying to populate a table with a subset of data from a select query and I want this table to be recreated at regular intervals. 
I tried to create an event which inserts records but it duplicates the records.
I then tried to drop and then create the table in an event but it tells me the table already exists

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablea;
CREATE TABLE tablea;
INSERT INTO tablea 
SELECT * from tableb WHERE etc.
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you in the right schema?  I ask as your drop table command is fine and if you are in the right schema (`use whateverdb;`), it will work.

Your commands all look ok *if they are summarised.*

if tablea exists in your current schema:

```
drop table if exists tablea;
```

is fine

to create a table, you need to specify the fields eg.

```
create table tablea (column1 varchar(20), column2 int, etc etc);
```

or better still, if the tables are the same structure, you could ignore that part and create the table with a create table like statement:

```
drop table if exists tablea;
create table tablea like tableb;
insert into tablea select * from tableb where column1 = whatever;
```

If tablea doesn't need the same properties as tableb, you can even do:

```
 drop table if exists tablea;
 create table tableb as select * from tableb where column1 = whatever;
```

The only disadvantage of this method over the stament above it is that it will not carry through the defined keys and special properties (if there are any).

And finally, if you are going to be recreating tablea over and over again, then, after you have initially created tablea (`create table tablea like tableb;` ) you can just keep rerunning these two lines below:

```
truncate tablea;
insert into tablea select * from tableb where whatever;
```

will be best as truncate (empty the contents) is much quicker than drop and leave your keys/properties in tact.

Comment: Truncate doesnt work in a single event. It seems that any terminating action ";" causes the rest of the event statement to be deleted

Comment: Truncate works perfectly for what I needed. The issue was that I was missing the BEGIN and END in the event. Thanks for the pointer!